# Skip validation for one field, not all the schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following long schema:

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // some stuff, email, lastName ... etc
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
  password: {
    type: String,
    minLength: 8,
    maxLength: 120,
  }
})
```

And I am inside one of the routes, I want to save a document that I am editing, but I only want to skip one validation, not the entire schema, I want to skip the validation for the `firstName` field, but I want the rest of the fields to be validated.

Is there something that I can do in Mongoose such as:

```
userDoc.firstName = "new first name";
const newDoc = await userDoc.save({ validateBeforeSave: yes, but not for firstName })
```

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of Mongoose answered this question [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/discussions/12005#discussioncomment-3071050)

> Yeah, check out the pathsToSkip option for validate: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-validate